# Installation of Windows Mobile driver update hangs

Tags: windows-7, installation

I am installing a program on a PC called TopView. This program requires the Windows Mobile Device 6.1 installed, and offers to install it.

Fine, I accept that, and it begins the installation.

However, it just hangs after the first window closes. Using Process Explorer, I can see that it hangs on some DLL with wait:userrequest (or something similar), however, there is nowhere to do any user input.

I have tried the same program on another (virtual) machine, and it works like a charm.

The computer is running Windows 7 x64 SP1.

Comment: Maybe it helps to install the [Windows Mobile Device Center](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3182) manually on this computer before executing the TopView setup?

Comment: @Gene - that does not seem to do the big difference.. It still just hangs with the process, and showing some `ntdll.dll!RtIValidateHeap+0x170`